# How to stop listening for a message without killing a yesod-websocket connection?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm writing an app using `yesod-websockets`, and whenever I receive a "Start" message, I need to run a thread that continuously produces data and sends it to the client, until the client tells it to stop. The producer may also stop producing data on its own.

When the producer stops (regardless of whether it stopped producing on its own, or the client told it to stop), it goes back to the main loop and waits for another "Start" message to be received.

The code looks something like this (runnable minimal repro below):

```
wsApp :: WebSocketsT Handler ()
wsApp = 
  forever $ do
    msg <- receiveMsg
    case msg of
      StartMsg -> do
        race_
          (produceData)
          (whileM ((/= StopMsg) <$> receiveMsg))
```

The problem is that if `produceData` stops on its own, then the thread running `receiveMsg` will be cancelled, and this causes the websocket connection to be closed.

> 21/Mar/2018:08:21:06 +0000 [Error#yesod] Exception from Warp: ConnectionClosed @(app-0.0.0-5bzI9Onrk2fFepGGsdocDz:Application src/Application.hs:122:15)

Is there a way to cancel a thread that's listening on the connection, without killing the connection?

Here's a minimal repro:

```
wsApp :: WebSocketsT Handler ()
wsApp = forever $ do
  race_
    (receiveData :: WebSocketsT Handler Text)
    (pure ())
  $logDebug "Trying again"
```

The second thread will finish, and the first one will be cancelled, causing the connection to be killed.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this, but why are you stopping the thread that's writing data if you don't want the connection to close? You could just produce a message saying there won't be any more data at the end of `produceData`, wait indefinitely and make the client always send a stop message when they've read that there's no data right (at least I'm thinking that the problem is that you want to make sure the client had the chance to read all data before the connection is killed, if that's not it please elaborate).

Comment: @Cubic "why are you stopping the thread that's writing data if you don't want the connection to close?" -- The producer may stop producing, in which case it goes back to the main `forever` loop and waits for a new `Start` message to be sent, and start producing again. I don't want the connection to ever be killed (unless the user navigates away, of course).

Comment: @Cubic I've edited the question, I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a more graceful solution, I ended up using an `IORef Bool` to synchronize the websockets thread and the producer thread.

```
wsApp :: WebSocketsT Handler ()
wsApp = do
  producing <- newIORef False
  forever $ do
    msg <- receiveMsg
    case msg of
      StartMsg -> do
        whenM (not <$> readIORef producing) $ do
          atomicWriteIORef producing True
          void . async $ produceData producing
      StopMsg -> atomicWriteIORef producing False

produceData :: IORef Bool -> WebSocketsT Handler ()
produceData producing =
  whenM (readIORef producing) $
    case produce of
      Nothing -> atomicWriteIORef producing False
      Just x  -> sendMsg x >> produceData producing
```